# ConcurrentModificationException when deleting

Tags: java, concurrentmodification

Usually when I see `ConcurrentModificationException`, it is due to iterating over a list and deleting something. In my case, I simply have a reference to the list and am trying to delete something from it. Here is my code:

```
getList(Client.class).remove(client);
```

This throws a `ConcurrentModificationException`. `classToListMap` is a declared like so

```
private Map<Class, ObservableList> classToListMap;
```

And here is the getList() function:

```
public <T> List<T> getList(Class T) {
    return classToListMap.get(T);
}
```

Any ideas on why this could be throwing the exception?

Here is the full function that throws the exception:

```
private synchronized void deleteClient() {
    DefaultMutableTreeNode node = getRightClickedNode();
    if (node.getUserObject() instanceof Client == false) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please select a client to delete");
        return;
    }
    TreeSelectionListener[] listeners = getTreeSelectionListeners();
    for(TreeSelectionListener listener : listeners){
        removeTreeSelectionListener(listener);
    }
    ((DefaultTreeModel)getModel()).removeNodeFromParent(node);
    Client client = (Client) node.getUserObject();
    applicationContext.getDataRepository().getList(Client.class).remove(client);  //!!!!!!<-- Throws exception
    applicationContext.fireUpdate(new UpdateEvent(UpdateEvent.Type.DELETE, client, new UnknownEvent(this)));
    for(TreeSelectionListener listener : listeners){
        addTreeSelectionListener(listener);
    }
}
```

Here is the complete stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.remove(AbstractList.java:380)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.remove(AbstractCollection.java:293)
    at com.dvsd.profmetric.ui.gui.client.gui.ClientTree.deleteClient(ClientTree.java:147)
    at com.dvsd.profmetric.ui.gui.client.gui.ClientTree.access$300(ClientTree.java:39)
    at com.dvsd.profmetric.ui.gui.client.gui.ClientTree$3.actionPerformed(ClientTree.java:121)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:376)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:833)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:877)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6527)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6292)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4883)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

`classToListMap` is being filled like so:

```
private void createClassToListMap() {
        classToListMap = new LinkedHashMap<Class, ObservableList>();

        classToListMap.put(ManagementProfessional.class, managementProfessionalList);
        classToListMap.put(AdministrativeProfessional.class, administrativeProfessionalList);
...
```

And the `ObservableLists` are `org.jdesktop.observablecollections.ObservableList;` being created like:

```
List<ProfitMargin> profitMargins = simulation.getProfitMarginList();
profitMarginList = ObservableCollections.observableList(profitMargins);
```

Where `ObservableCollections` is a `org.jdesktop.observablecollections.ObservableCollections;`

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell from the limited code you've supplied. Can you share a full snippet please?

Comment: It would be interesting to see how you fill your classToListMap, and what's ObservableList in your case.

Comment: From my guess you're removing UI objects which is used by awt itself while processing the event. One way would be making it just invisible.

Comment: Still need more information about the initialization of `ObservableList` instances that are stored in `classToListMap`. Do you create these objects yourself? Are you registering an observer on them? Or, if they come from elsewhere, what are they?

Comment: Which line in that method is throwing the exception? (Hint:  is it being thrown in that enhanced-for statement?)

Comment: @manzur Ive added the code for it being filled. The lists contain JPA entities which are simple POJOs

Comment: @Makoto I have marked the line where the exception is being thrown. It is the line right after the first for loop

Answer (score 3):

You haven't provided complete information, but I'm guessing that the `Observable` part of `ObservableList` means that changes in list content are reported to an observer, and that observer might be iterating over the list or trying to make its own modifications in the callback that is fired when you remove the element. Post a complete stack trace and information about the list observer callback if you need more help.

Comment: Thanks, just added the stack trace. Ill take a look at the observable list